# TERADATA: Unwanted whitespaces generated while updating a row

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table called **UDB.feed_counter** (feed_name VARCHAR(255), feed_counter VARCHAR(255)) which keeps track of the highest number from some other table: 
[image: Image1]

when updating the number (feed_counter) I use this query:

```
update UDB.feed_counter from(select max(distinct LFD_NR) AS LFD_NR from DWH.ART) A SET feed_counter=A.LFD_NR where feed_name='devicecataloglocal_art';
```

For some reason when I update feed_counter with this query I get some whitespaces in front of a number

[image: Image2]

Why is that happening??

When I do this: `select max(distinct CAST(LFD_NR AS INTEGER)) from DWH.ART;` I don't get any whitespaces

Can someone explain?

Additionally I should add that LFD_NR from DWH.ART is a string containing a number.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when VARCHAR columns values are updated from CHAR column values, the targeted VARCHAR columns are populated with exactly same value as that of CHAR column value from source by removing trailing whitespaces. But no whitespaces are addded in front.

I guess, the issue is with LFD_NR column of DWH.ART table.
Try selecting values from DWH.ART without casting as INTEGER:

**select max(distinct LFD_NR) from DWH.ART;**

There is a chance the LFD_NR column has whitespaces in front for the values.